# Direct post to AWS S3 from ReactNative (iOS) with signed request

Tags: ios, node.js, heroku, amazon-s3, react-native

I am trying to recreate the [Heroku example](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node) of uploading user submitted images in React Native, but keep getting 400 errors from AWS.

The images are from the iOS camera roll. I have the uri to the image and a base64 encoded version of the image. The mime type is `image/jpeg`. So far, I have set everything up as Heroku stated, but am having trouble making the file I send the proper shape. I've added my code below for clarification.

I am using [react-native-image-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-picker) to select images from the camera roll

client side code

```
module.exports = React.createClass({
...

openPhotos() { // called on a button press, opens camera roll
    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
      if (response.didCancel) return;
      if (response.error) return Alert.alert('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      this.getSignedRequest(response);
    });
  },
getSignedRequest(pickerResp) {
  // image uri IS pickerResp.uri AS IS `data:image/jpg;base64,${pickerResp.data}`
  var file = {
    uri: pickerResp.uri, // ALSO WORKS `data:image/jpg;base64,${pickerResp.data}`,
    name: `${this.props.email}.jpg`,
    type: 'image/jpeg'
  };
  var body = new FormData();
  body.append('file', file);

  fetch(`${api.TEST_API}sign-s3?file-name=${file.name}.jpg&file-type=${file.type}`, {
    method: "GET"
  }).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
    Alert.alert("GOT SIGNED REQUEST",data.url);
    fetch(data.signedRequest, { method: 'put', body: body }).then(resp => resp.json()).then(data => {
      this.setState({uploadedFile: true});
      this.props.toSignup();
    }).catch(err => Alert.alert("Server Error", "Could not upload profile photo."))
  }).catch(err => {
    Alert.alert('S3 Signed Request Error',"Look at the Logs");
    console.log(err);
  })
},

...
};
```

server side code

AWS NPM package : [aws-sdk]

```
// get signature to upload client side to s3
apiRouter.get('/sign-s3', function(req, res) {
  console.log('signing s3')
  const s3 = new aws.S3(); // automatically loads key and secret
  const fileName = req.query['file-name'];
  const fileType = req.query['file-type'];
  const s3Params = {
    Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
    Key: fileName,
    Expires: 60,
    ContentType: fileType,
    ACL: 'public-read'
  };

  s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3Params, (err, data) => {
    if(err) return console.log(err)
    const returnData = {
      signedRequest: data,
      url: `https://${S3_BUCKET}.s3.amazonaws.com/${fileName}`
    };
    console.log(returnData)
    res.json(returnData);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`` fetch(`${api.TEST_API}sign-s3?file-name=${file.name}.jpg&file-type=${file.type} ``

The fetch request here is adding an extra `.jpg` onto the end of the filename described, so when you try to upload to S3, it is rejected because the payload doesn't match the prior request. Also, the XMLHttpRequest suggested by Heroku works fine with the file structured as you have it, but with the base64 data instead (below).

```
var file = {
  uri: `data:image/jpg;base64,${pickerResp.data}`, //pickerResp.uri,
  type: 'image/jpeg',
  name: `${this.props.email}.jpg`,
};
```

The following XML HTTP request will send the image in its encoded form to S3, where a simple GET request or image src property can access the file.

```
function uploadFile(file, signedRequest, url, cb) {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('PUT', signedRequest);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      if(xhr.status === 200) {
        cb()
      } else {
        alert('Could not upload file.');
      }
    }
  };
  xhr.send(file);
};
```